# drawIntro undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-svg

I am using html5 on Windows 7 and am trying to use jQuery SVG described [here](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html).

It calls for the following line of code in the html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function ($) {$('#svgintro').svg({onLoad: drawIntro});});</script>
```

However, this causes the JavaScript console to return the error message

```
ReferenceError: drawIntro is not defined
```

I have been unable to find a discussion about this error on the web or where it is suppoed to be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a function `drawIntro`. It should look like below. I have just used the example code given in the page that you mentioned. This should work. The main problem was you didn't had defined a function. Just by copying the function might also work. Hope this helps

```
<div id="svgintro"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#svgintro').svg({onLoad: drawIntro});
function drawIntro(svg) { 
    svg.circle(75, 75, 50, 
        {fill: 'none', stroke: 'red', strokeWidth: 3}); 
    var g = svg.group({stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 2}); 
    svg.line(g, 15, 75, 135, 75); 
    svg.line(g, 75, 15, 75, 135); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.  I can now see my error relating to drawIntro.  Where I still have a problem is that I now get the error message TypeError: $(...).svg is not a function.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Have you included `jquery.svg.js` in your html. If you have copied the code from this post make sure that it is in correct path.

Comment: Yes.  It seems to be seeing that file because I get the message [11:19:55.546] GET http://localhost:8080/indexDir/js/jquery.svg.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 20ms].  Thanks, Peter.